# Счетчик страниц слайдера slick

Tags: css, вёрстка, slick.js

Есть некоторое количество слайдов, например 10, которые отображаются по 3 и по 3 листаются. Как сделать счетчик именно страниц слайдера, а не самих слайдов?
Т.е должно получиться 1/3 2/3 3/3.
использую slick slider

Использую данный js код, который считает именно слайды
, где #slider - обертка всех слайдов
#cp - спан с заведомо известным количеством страниц, если можно его адаптировать, чтобы скрипт сам подсчитывал количество страниц, было бы вообще здорово.

```
$("#slider").on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    $("#cp").text(currentSlide + 1);
});
```

Comment: В чем проблема разделить на 3?

Comment: @OliverPatterson спасибо